# Mp4/m4a audio streaming issue in iOS9 using AudioToolBox

Tags: ios, mp4, audio-streaming, ios9, audiotoolbox

I have a audio streaming app that streams music from a network resource with audio files as mp4's encoded as AAC using Azure's Media Encoder. I'm using open source library's https://github.com/muhku/FreeStreamer https://github.com/douban/DOUAudioStreamer, which both use [Apple's Stream Parser](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/AudioStreamReference/#//apple_ref/c/func/AudioFileStreamParseBytes) from the AudioToolBox framework to stream audio, but on iOS9 the framework throws a [kAudioFileStreamError_InvalidFile](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/AudioStreamReference/#//apple_ref/c/econst/kAudioFileStreamError_InvalidFile) error. Interestingly apps compiled with the iOS9 SDK continue to stream the same file perfectly on iOS7/8 devices, but not iOS9.

Now i can't figure out if Apple broke something in iOS9, or we have the files encoded wrong on our end, but they play just fine on both iOS 7/8 but not 9. Here is a sample file from our server which plays just fine on iOS 7/8 but not 9 http://patarims.streaming.mediaservices.windows.net/858959cc-a7c2-4053-9f41-9ad32b406a8b/eyhqG1mC_AAC_und_ch2_128kbps.mp4

If anyone could point me in the right direction, how do i go about debugging the issue? Do we need to re-encode our files in some specific way?

Comment: I am also facing the same issue..If you find any solution please share it.